# Can't able to add moviepy as an external library in AWS Glue job python shell

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, moviepy

I have to use moviepy.editor in my glue job (python shell) but when I was importing it, it gives me error

> No module named "Moviepy"

So I added .whl file of moviepy on a s3 path and added in security configuration >> python library path .
It worked for some modules' unpackaging but fails on others due to version incompatibility of some other modules on which moviepy is dependent .

Here is the error logs of glue job

[image: Error logs 1]
[image: Error logs 2]

I have tried to add whl files of numpy and urllib with compatible versions but it didn't work.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, errors or other text. Just copy the original text to your question.